# Passing object into the method Perl

Tags: perl, oop, object, perl-module

I am dealing with the following problem. I am newbie in Perl.

The idea is that I have a class, it has array as member/field (in hash).
Let's name this class `ProductContainer`.

I have another class `Product`. These Classes are in separate files (separate modules). So I need to just add a `Product` object into `ProductContainer` object (internal array).

Simple example what I need in Java.

```
public class ProductContainer {
 private List<Product> mProductsList;
 public addProduct(Product product) {
  this.mProductList.add(product);
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you use [bless](http://p3rl.org/bless), [Moo](http://p3rl.org/Moo), [Moose](http://p3rl.org/Moose), or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not clear what exactly you are asking, as you haven't shown any Perl code.

If you are using [bless](http://p3rl.org/bless) for your objects, the following shows you how to do that. I put all the packages in the same file. Also, note that the `add` method checks the type of its argument.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

{   package ProductContainer;

    use Carp;

    sub new { bless {}, shift }

    sub add {
        my $self = shift;
        my $product = shift;
        croak "Invalid member" unless UNIVERSAL::DOES($product, 'Product');
        push @{ $self->{mProductsList} }, $product;
    }
}

{   package Product;

    sub new {
        my $class = shift;
        bless { name => shift }, $class
    }
}

my $p  = 'Product'->new('Product 1');
my $pc = 'ProductContainer'->new;
$pc->add($p);
$pc->add('Product 2');   # Exception!
```

Comment: sorry ,for not providing code, this is exactly what I need, I am using bless